# collect numbers and convert them to date in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datetime

I have 3 scopes in angularjs, one for year, one for month and one for day coming from 3 input boxes. I want to combine them as date, the following code insert the date correctly but with 22:00:00 added to it like  2019-06-01 22:00:00.000.
How to insert the date only without time

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="form-group has-error">
        <label class="title_lable">Year:</label>
        <input id="code" type="number" class="form-control input-sm"
               ng-model="year">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group has-error">
        <label class="title_lable">Latin Description:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"
               ng-model="latindesc">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="title_lable">Local Description:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"
               ng-model="localdesc">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="title_lable">Month:</label>
        <select ng-show="lang==1" class="form-control input-sm"
                ng-model="month"
                ng-options="m.mnthid as m.mnthanm for m in months">
        </select>
        <select ng-show="lang==0" class="form-control input-sm"
                ng-model="month"
                ng-options="m.mnthid as m.mnthenm for m in months">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="title_lable">Day:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="day">
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular

```
var dFrom = new Date($scope.month + '/' + ($scope.day + 1) + '/' + $scope.year );
        var days = $scope.ndays;
        console.log(days);
        var todate = new Date($scope.month + '/' + ($scope.day +1) + '/' + $scope.year);
        todate = addDays(todate, days - 1);
        console.log(todate);

        var vacation = {
            Sys_Key: $scope.syskey,
            Vac_Code: $scope.code,
            L_Desc: $scope.latindesc,
            A_Desc: $scope.localdesc,
            V_Start_Date: $scope.day,
            V_Month: $scope.month,
            V_Days_Count: $scope.ndays,
            V_Year: $scope.year,
            From_Date: dFrom,
            To_Date: todate
        }
```

---

```
function addDays(startDate, numberOfDays) {
    var returnDate = new Date(
        startDate.getFullYear(),
        startDate.getMonth(),
        startDate.getDate() + numberOfDays,
        startDate.getHours(),
        startDate.getMinutes(),
        startDate.getSeconds()
    );
    return returnDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the code insert the date correctly but with 22:00:00 added to it like 2019-06-01 22:00:00.000. How to insert the date only without time

Under-the-hood the date is parsed to 00:00 hours UTC time. The standard `.toString` method displays it as local time.

```js
var d = new Date("2019-06-01");

console.log(d.toString());

console.log(d.toISOString());
```

If you want it parsed to local time append "T00:00"

```js
var d = new Date("2019-06-01T00:00");

console.log(d.toString());

console.log(d.toISOString());
```

When the time zone offset is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as local time.

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Answer (score 1):

When adding in javascript, be sure you are using numerical values and not strings. You can convert strings to integers with `parseInt(string)`

Comment: Please share the addDays() function code. Its possible this might work:
`todate = addDays(todate, parseInt(days) - 1);`

Comment: function addDays(startDate, numberOfDays) {
    var returnDate = new Date(
        startDate.getFullYear(),
        startDate.getMonth(),
        startDate.getDate() + numberOfDays,
        startDate.getHours(),
        startDate.getMinutes(),
        startDate.getSeconds());
    return returnDate;
}

Comment: @hassanzi Please [edit] your question and include all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as,

```js
let dateString = "05/05/1997";

let date = new Date(dateString);

console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
      day:"2-digit",
      month:"2-digit",
      year:"numeric"
    }));
```

Please checkout following link,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: kindly how to apply it on my example, thanks in advance

Comment: While some platforms will parse that date string properly, it is not guaranteed to work on all platforms. It is best to follow the [simplified ISO 8601 format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format)